# How to make a proper POST request in Rails (while converting from Curl)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to convert a Curl request into my Rails app. It seems that the online converter that I'm using is kind of buggy.

The current state is:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'

class Listing < ApplicationRecord

    def getit2
        uri = URI.parse("https://www.somedomain.com/api/public/v1.0/markers/list")
        request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
        request.content_type = "application/json"
        request["Origin"] = "https://www.somedomain.com"
        request["Accept-Language"] = "en-US,en;q=0.9,ar;q=0.8,bg;q=0.7,de;q=0.6,es;q=0.5,fr;q=0.4,he;q=0.3,hu;q=0.2,it;q=0.1,ms;q=0.1,nl;q=0.1,nb;q=0.1,ru;q=0.1,sk;q=0.1,sv;q=0.1,tr;q=0.1,vi;q=0.1,zh-CN;q=0.1,zh;q=0.1"
        request["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/535.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Mobile Safari/537.36"
        request["Accept"] = "application/json"
        request["Referer"] = "https://www.google.co.uk"
        request["Cookie"] = "_pxhd=2f7043c8ae569c7ddddd12207ac90cca0ef2a40d61378c41112492:46c5aca1-7401-11e9-ab6d-251d1e721a9f; _gcl_au=1.1.2102026563.1557588441; Infinite_lastSearch_key=; Infinite_user_id_key=7ba2e36f-2a47-46bf-a275-04d5b2cbe965; Infinite_ab_tests_context_key={%22context%22:{%22price_estimation%22:%22false%22%2C%22display_sold%22:%22false%22%2C%22display_sold_v2%22:%22true%22%2C%22price_estimation_v2%22:%22true%22%2C%22price_estimation_v3%22:%22false%22}%2C%22values%22:{%22price_estimation%22:%22false%22%2C%22display_sold%22:%22false%22%2C%22display_sold_v2%22:%22true%22%2C%22price_estimation_v2%22:%22true%22%2C%22price_estimation_v3%22:%22false%22}}; _pxvid=46c5aca1-7401-11e9-ab6d-251d1e721a9f; _ga=GA1.3.1522435888.1557588443; _gid=GA1.3.1336624029.1560436285; AWSELB=CD9FE1B30E32EDF52EB77EE30BE426CF7F363C127FE2A9BC2F70F9F1CDD10FF86A1B4095995C86A57A485BDD3A564FE18D63589FAE6A0457DFADBDFF864B86DAA86999D390; _sp_id.549d=457ec9d1-91b0-4e92-a50a-1d6517ccb887.1560168270.6.1560586655.1560522000.895c4b58-2ee1-45ca-bf34-b0e4716eac0d; _ud=0f90bb52e08b81cc0d5493b6de1c53b81d7a25c4-cid=116ea8bc-6bbd-4661-b5a6-f65725ec0e6d&_ts=1560595069960; _dc_gtm_UA-26019961-1=1; _px3=d331cc7dc802bed39645428247a9f83be0c89dc82d9c549bad4bc2bfe2823676:XUO7Topo8ACRMvx9jjEXR5qW+CpujeC0thydfP6jHjpGr4G0iPU2Qm4m5IDAn/Pk8qsHxJKaowm58pMULV9MIw==:1000:dqOcC/gfWU9y/hUxvT6akY2ZBKdd+M5HDrxR9UaggnszreSjIkckWJVscq59PjoRCAiNJhfIEGaHC++sor4DUOc4iwZRQgthPouxNYgqkeKCqjPXwOrsSBppi1Yh3L3AF+2Kv/msYsE+F7ol8ALbGQQp3LkYOa4ta1RIZeLhHTQ="
        request["Connection"] = "keep-alive"
        request.body = JSON.dump({
          "sortBy" => "auto",
          "areaId" => "the area",
          "isStreetAreaId" => false,
          "filters" => "{"dealTypes":["FOR_SALE"],"addBulletinFromPrivate":true,"addBulletinFromAgent":true,"addProjects":true,"propertyTypes":[],"conditions":[]}",
          "zoom" => 11.366136034830756,
          "NELat" => 1,
          "NELng" => 1,
          "SWLat" => 1,
          "SWLng" => 1,
          "slim" => true
        })

        req_options = {
          use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
        }

        response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
          http.request(request)
        end
    end
end
```

And the console is raising this error:

> /app/models/listing.rb:38: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER,
>   expecting '}'
>           "filters" => "{"dealTypes":["FOR_SALE"],"addBulletinFr...
>                                    ^

It seems that it fails in the `filters` data point. How should it be structured to create a valide request?

Comment: Use a dedicated gem for that. [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) is a great example.

Comment: @Richard-Degenne tried rest-client without success

Comment: Also, I see that you are trying to do string interpolation within your `filter` field. You don't need to do that, since `JSON.dump` with recursively serialize data structures.

Comment: `"{"dealTypes":["FOR_SALE"],"addBulletinFromPrivate":true,"addBulletinFromAgent":true,"addProjects":true,"propertyTypes":[],"conditions":[]}",` I suspect that string doesn't get parsed correctly. I'd try escaping the inner quotes `"` with a backslash like `"{\"dealTypes\":[\"FOR_SALE\"],\"addBulletinFromPrivate\":true,\"addBulletinFromAgent\":true,\"addProjects\":true,\"propertyTypes\":[],\"conditions\":[]}",`

Answer (score 1):

Use a dedicated gem for that. [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) is a great example.

```rb
class MyAPI
  include HTTParty

  base_uri 'https://www.somedomain.com/api/public/v1.0'
  headers 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'
end
```

```rb
MyAPI.post(
  '/markers/list', body: {
    "sortBy" => "auto",
    # ...  
  }.to_json
)
```

Of course, depending on the actual contents of the response, you will need to do some parsing, but HTTParty is able to parse automatically if the response `Content-Type` header is correctly set.